# Python Webscraping bloomberg site for company addresses - getting 'Are you a robot' captcha while fetching the html content from URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, captcha

My python file is in the scrapy project and my settings.py in spyder has robotstxt_obey = False.
I have successfully installed and imported, pandas, scrapy, spyder, beautifulsoup, requests.

but still when the below code executes, i get "Are you a robot?" captcha error while getting fetching the HTML code.
I have seen many posts with answers to similar question. However, I am not able to resolve the error.
I cannot put the entire code, but putting the main body that has the trouble. 
I hope my question is clear, please help. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
if pd.isnull(row['Company']) == False or pd.isnull(row['Domain']) ==
False :
          #OR (pd.isnull(row['Company']) == False AND pd.isnull(row['Company']) == False)
          # pd.isnull(row['City']) == True and and pd.isnull(row['Address']) == True
          listUrl = []
          print(row['Domain'])
          if pd.isnull(row['Company']) == False:
              listUrl = get_urls(row['Company'] +' bloomberg', 10, 'en')
          else:
              listUrl = get_urls(row['Domain'] + ' bloomberg', 10, 'en')
          for item1 in listUrl:
              print("in bloomberg 1")
              print(item1)
              if 'www.bloomberg.com/profile/company/' in item1:
                  print("in bloomberg 2")
                  res = requests.get(item1, headers=headers)
                  print(res.content)
                  soup2 = bs(res.content, 'html.parser')
                  items = soup2.findAll("div", {"class": "infoTableItemValue__e188b0cb"})
                   print(items)
```

Comment: please fix and format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue but I could fix it by adding "user-agent": Mozilla/80.0 into my requests header. I would also suggest to add some error handling to avoid having your code blown up when you can't establish a connection due to being blocked.

```
for url in start_links[0:]:
    try:
        response = requests.get(url[0], timeout=5, cookies=cookies, headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/80.0"})
        print(response, url)

    except NewConnectionError:
        continue
```